# How to move the position of labelling in feynmp?

Tags: feynman, feynmp-auto

What if I want label on other side of vertex or **fermion**?

```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{fmffile}{elecdig}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
    \fmfpen{thin}
    \fmfleft{i1,i2,ip,i3,i4} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2,op,o3,o4}
    \fmfpen{thick}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$v$}{i3,o3}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=Spin Direction}{i4,o4}
    %\fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$spin=+\frac{1}{2}$}{v2,o2}
    \fmf{dashes,label=It can't be ${\hat{e}_R}$ but it is $e_R$}{ip,op}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=1}{o2,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=1}{i2,i1}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$v_{new}$}{o2,i2} 
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=Spin Direction}{i1,o1}
    %\fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$spin=+\frac{1}{2}$}{v1,o1}
    \fmflabel{Frame $1$.}{i3}
    \fmflabel{Frame $2$.}{i2}
    \end{fmfgraph*} 
    \end{fmffile}
    \end{center}
```

**I want to move v_new to another side**
There is also a problem when I am not using **\fmfpen{thick or thin}** and the second line from above automatically thin compare to others.
i.e.,

```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{fmffile}{elecdig}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
    %\fmfpen{thin}
    \fmfleft{i1,i2,ip,i3,i4} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2,op,o3,o4}
    %\fmfpen{thick}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$v$}{i3,o3}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=Spin Direction}{i4,o4}
    %\fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$spin=+\frac{1}{2}$}{v2,o2}
    \fmf{dashes,label=It can't be ${\hat{e}_R}$ but it is $e_R$}{ip,op}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=1}{o2,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=1}{i2,i1}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$v_{new}$}{o2,i2} 
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=Spin Direction}{i1,o1}
    %\fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$spin=+\frac{1}{2}$}{v1,o1}
    \fmflabel{Frame $1$.}{i3}
    \fmflabel{Frame $2$.}{i2}
    \end{fmfgraph*} 
    \end{fmffile}
    \end{center}
```

this gives,

[image]

I am restating the problem with reference to this image:

1. 2nd line from above is thin compare to others
2. I don't know how to shift label $v_{new}$ to other side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer that doesn't use `feynmf`, but uses a new package called [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)).  Ti*k*Z-Feynman has inbuilt support for momentum arrows which, in this case, can be used to indicate the velocity and spin direction of fermions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}\noindent
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] 
                {a -- [fermion, momentum=\(v\), momentum'=spin] b}; \newline
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] 
                {a -- [fermion, reversed momentum=\(v\), momentum'=spin] b}; \newline
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is cool!!!

Comment: @LoveGrover I'm glad you like it.  Feel free to post other questions on TeX.SX if you have any more question about Ti*k*Z-Feynman :)

Comment: Got your site. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare an explicit label position in the argument of `\fmf`; in your case, the code should read

```
\fmf{fermion,tension=1,label=$v_{\mathrm{new}}$,label.side=left}{o2,i2}
```

I took the liberty of adding `\mathrm` for the subscript "new".

Concerning your other point, I fear I cannot help you. I get all lines with the same thickness. Is it maybe a rendering problem? Notice furthermore that in your first piece of code

```
\fmfpen{thin}
\fmfleft{i1,i2,ip,i3,i4} 
\fmfright{o1,o2,op,o3,o4}
\fmfpen{thick}
```

the declaration `\fmfpen{thin}` is useless: you are not drawing any line, and you are setting the pen to thick right after it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was helpful. About the thin. I was moving it a lot and before posting it I added a thick pen line. I did not remove it because of laziness.

Comment: Using only \fmfpen{thick} resolve the problem but without defining thickness or defining it to thin doesn't help at all. Should I compile it online?